# esper illegalStateException and SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, http, esper

As soon as I send an Event via HTTP to the Esper Engine, I get some errors. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

The event is either defined in the config or in the deployment.

```
16:08:43,549 [Thread-21] INFO  [EsperHttpServiceClassicRunnable] Incoming connection service 'myservice' from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
16:08:43,550 [Thread-21] INFO  [EsperHttpServiceClassicRunnable] Incoming connection service 'myservice' from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
16:08:43,555 [Thread-21] INFO  [EsperHttpServiceClassicRunnable] Incoming connection service 'myservice' from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
16:08:43,662 [Thread-71] ERROR [EsperHttpRequestHandler] Error processing Http GET request target '/favicon.ico' :Null event type name parameter
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null event type name parameter
        at com.espertech.esper.event.EventAdapterServiceImpl.getExistsTypeByName(EventAdapterServiceImpl.java:310)
        at com.espertech.esperio.http.EsperHttpRequestHandler.makeCacheEntry(EsperHttpRequestHandler.java:94)
        at com.espertech.esperio.http.EsperHttpRequestHandler.handle(EsperHttpRequestHandler.java:71)
        at com.espertech.esperio.http.EsperHttpRequestHandler.handle(EsperHttpRequestHandler.java:59)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.doService(HttpService.java:375)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.handleRequest(HttpService.java:290)
        at com.espertech.esperio.http.core.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:47)
16:08:48,560 [Thread-72] ERROR [WorkerThread] I/O error: Read timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:92)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:59)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpServerConnection.receiveRequestHeader(AbstractHttpServerConnection.java:247)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.handleRequest(HttpService.java:246)
        at com.espertech.esperio.http.core.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:47)
16:08:48,560 [Thread-73] ERROR [WorkerThread] I/O error: Read timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:92)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:59)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpServerConnection.receiveRequestHeader(AbstractHttpServerConnection.java:247)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.handleRequest(HttpService.java:246)
        at com.espertech.esperio.http.core.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:47)
16:08:48,662 [Thread-71] ERROR [WorkerThread] I/O error: Read timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:92)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:59)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpServerConnection.receiveRequestHeader(AbstractHttpServerConnection.java:247)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.handleRequest(HttpService.java:246)
        at com.espertech.esperio.http.core.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:47)
```

I suspect it has something to do with the `favicon.ico`, but i'm not sure. The request is done via Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is the first exception "IllegalStateException: Null event type name parameter". There is a missing parameter apparently which is the name of the event type. It may be what is causing subsequent exceptions.